# Calling API again if it returns Http 401

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client

I am calling below API using jersey

```
JsonObject response = ConnectionUtil.getwebTarget()
                                        .request().
                 header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ access_token)
                                        .get(JsonObject.class);
```

Here `accessToken` is variable which got value by calling another API.  Now if response.getStatus() returnd 401 I want to call the API to get token and will call the above commnad again. how can I stop myself from duplication?
As of now I am writing below code.

```
JsonObject response = ConnectionUtil.getwebTarget()
                                            .request().
                     header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ access_token)
                                            .get(JsonObject.class);
  if(response.getStatus()==401)
  {
    accessToken= new AccessToken().getAccessToken();
    JsonObject response = ConnectionUtil.getwebTarget()
                                            .request()
                                            .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ access_token)
                                            .get(JsonObject.class);
}
```

how can I reduce writing the code of line  `JsonObject response` twice. I atleast want to check twice 401 code before throwing customized exception

I am new to `java programming`. can somebody tell me logic. its basic coding but I am still struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a subroutine.

```
private JsonObject doRequest(AccessToken access_token) {
    return ConnectionUtil.getwebTarget()
             .request()
             .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ access_token)
             .get(JsonObject.class);
}
```

and then use it twice

```
JsonObject response = doRequest(access_token);
if (response.getStatus() == 401) {
    access_token = new AccessToken().getAccessToken();
    response = doRequest(access_token);
}
```

'doRequest' might not be the best name to choose, but I don't know what the big picture is - i.e., what is it actually doing?

Comment: thank you @user13784117 . But if again and again 401 error comes then it will go to infinite loop.

Comment: There is no loop.  You 'doRequest' once. If that fails, then you 'doRequest' again. That is the end of it.   It is an **if** statement, not any of the loop statements (**for**, **while**, or **do**).

Answer (score 1):

this is a good candidate for a `do...while` loop. `do...while` loops guarantee execution at least once, and are a great native java tool to implement this type of retry semantic.

```
AccessToken accessToken;
JsonObject response;
int retryCount = 0;
final int MAX_RETRIES = 2;

do {
    accessToken= new AccessToken().getAccessToken();
    response = ConnectionUtil.getwebTarget().request().header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ access_token).get(JsonObject.class);
} while (response.getStatus()==401 && retryCount++ < MAX_RETRIES);

if (response.getStatus() == 401) {
    throw new CustomException("");
}
```

Worth checking out [this reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) as well if you want to learn more

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a policy based retry, you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651236/how-to-implement-a-retry-mechanism-in-jersey-client-java).

```
RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy()
  .retryIf((ClientResponse response) -> response.getStatus() == 401)
  .withDelay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .withMaxRetries(3);

Failsafe.with(retryPolicy).get(() -> webResource.post(ClientResponse.class, input));
```